# tfs 2012 publish does not work

Tags: publish, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my asp.net mvc application to another server but getting this error:

```
Error   101 Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ...
```

I have installed the Web Management service on the server and it is running?

I have also tried to queue a build in tfs which builds fine on the buildserver however the deployment is not happening:

```
 /p:DeployOnBuild=True
 /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
 /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
 /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://myserver:8172/msdeploy.axd 
 /p:MsDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
 /p:UserName=myserver\myadmin
 /p:Password=mypassword 
 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
 /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/myappname"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Web Deploy package from WebPI and ensure that you have ports 443 and 8172 open on your firewall.

[Web Deploy Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39277) if you don't PI

Comment: I've had problems if I've installed things in the wrong order. If I've installed sql server after I've installed the web deploy package I find it borks my installation. At that point all I can do to get it to work is to completely uninstall webdeploy and reinstall it. Sounds like I'm repeating things you've already tried, have you already tried that?